androdjs - how app knows to serve index.html?
I am learning androidjs from this example:
https://medium.com/@Chhekur/how-to-build-android-apps-with-node-js-using-android-js-2aa4643be87b
https://github.com/android-js/sample-app/tree/master/story-app
The code in main.js of this project is only:
    const back = require('androidjs').back;
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');


// defin signal save-data to listen from front process

back.on('save-data', function(filepath, msg){
    fs.writeFile(path.join(filepath, 'data.txt'), msg, function(err){
        if(err) throw err;
        console.log('file saved')
    })
})

back.on('get-data', function(filepath){
    fs.readFile(path.join(filepath, 'data.txt'), 'utf-8', function(err, data){
        if(err) back.send('get-data-result', '@@');
        else back.send('get-data-result', data);
    })
})

However app somehow serves index.html and it works, because I've already compiled it.
But I am confused, because there are no references in the code of main.js ,nether in package.json to index.html. So how an app knows that it should serve index.html as a first screen?

All it needs is the location of the folder that contains the pages it's supposed to serve and to look there for index.html. That is why these kinds of tools usually have a standardized project structure. The NodeJS package.json is a great example - goes in the root of the project folder, uses a standardized name, and can optionally contain the entry point to start the program which could be in a nested path of folders.
